# How to create an html table using an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called($data) as follows,

```
print_e($data);


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PID] => 1
            [USER_NAME] => JOHN
            [JOINED_DATE] => 2022-01-31
            [JOINED_VALUE] => 23233.8
            [TOPUP_AMOUNT] => 58000
            [TOTAL_EXPENSES] => 3114.41
            [TOTAL_BALANCE] => 84348.21
        )
....
```

I need to fomat these array data in to a nice html table so anyone can easily identify the values without scroling. As an first attemp, I just tried to `echo` these variables by iterating through the loop. Here is my try.

```
foreach($data as $item){
    echo "$data[PID] | $data[USER_NAME]";
}
```

But I couldn't get the output as I wish.. Can someone show me how to print these data to a HTML table or just like normal dataset as above?

Update:

I need to get an output like below.

[image]

Comment: How you want your output? Give an example

Comment: Where is the problem? You know what HTML markup a table requires, yes? So make your script output the appropriate tags in the appropriate places then ...

Comment: If you're not familiar with HTML table markup, start with a [beginner's guide like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables). Outputting the rows and cells in PHP is then really no different from what you've already got, just with different strings in place of " | ".

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you wanted a html table from your array.

```
<?php
$data = Array(
    0 => Array(
        'PID' => 1,
        'USER_NAME' => 'JOHN',
        'JOINED_DATE' => '2022-01-31',
        'JOINED_VALUE' => 23233.80,
        'TOPUP_AMOUNT' => 58000.00,
        'TOTAL_EXPENSES' => 3114.41,
        'TOTAL_BALANCE' => 84348.21
    )
);
?>

<!-- HTML Code -->
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Pid</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Joined Date</th>
    <th>Joined Value</th>
    <th>Topup Amount</th>
    <th>Total Expenses</th>
    <th>Total Balance</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      foreach($data as $item){
        ?>
          <td><?= $item['PID'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $item['USER_NAME'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $item['JOINED_DATE'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $item['JOINED_VALUE'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $item['TOPUP_AMOUNT'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $item['TOTAL_EXPENSES'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $item['TOTAL_BALANCE'] ?></td>
        <?php
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I am not getting the result I need. Only the headers.

Comment: I am getting the $data from a query and directly it is used to get this output. But when I tried your answer with separate php, your code worked. But print_r($data ) is as same what I provided in my original file

Comment: It is working in localhost. But didnt wok on remote server.